# Why can't Kohana find my controller?

Tags: kohana, autoload

I have the following controller:

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct script access.');

class Controller_Static extends Controller_DefaultTemplate {

    public function action_index()
    {
        View::set_global('message', '<span class="highlight">This is a global message.</span>');

        $data = array (
            'siteTitle' => 'Kohana Test Site',
            'siteSubtitle' => 'A site to learn Kohana',
            'menu' => View::factory('blocks/menu'),
        );

        $view = View::factory('templates/layout', $data);
        $this->request->response = $view->render();
    }

}
```

but kohana gives me the error:

> ErrorException [ Fatal Error ]: Class
>   'Controller_DefaultTemplate' not found

although Eclipse can find the file (via F3) and I thought Kohana was able to find all classes via autoloading?

[image]

**How can I get Kohana to find the Controller_DefaultTemplate class so I can extend Controller_Static?**

Answer (score 0):

You must include file with definition of `Controller_DefaultTemplate`

Comment: I am working from this tutorial http://www.dealtaker.com/blog/2009/12/30/kohana-php-3-0-ko3-tutorial-part-3/ but it doesn't say anything about explicitly incuding the file which defines Controller_DefaultTemplate, how do I do that?

Comment: then probably you file is in other directory or have corrupted name, because if this file dont have includes then other script must include this file after include of detault template controler.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that my file name `defaultTemplate.php` was camel case, changing it to all-lowercase `defaultemplate.php` enabled Kohana to find the class inside it.